# Não recebo os dados do SELECT FROM

Tags: php, mysql, select

Eu estou fazendo um simples sistema de login mas eu nunca recebo uma linha verdadeira onde

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE 'email' = :email AND 'senha' = :senha";
```

Mas o email e a senha estão corretos, Função PHP:

```
public function logarUsuario(){
    try{
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE 'email' = :email AND 'senha' = :senha";
        $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
        $stmt -> bindParam(":email", $this->email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt -> bindParam(":senha", $this->senha, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt ->execute();
        return $stmt->fetch();
        echo $stmt->fetch();
    }catch (PDOException $e){
        echo "Error".$e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Aqui está o a programação enviando os dados para a classe usuario:

```
if (isset($_POST['logar'])):
    //Recebe os dados
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $senha = md5($_POST['senha']);

    //Salva os dados na classe usuario
    $user->setEmail($email);
    $user->setSenha($senha);
    //Tenta logar
    if($user->logarUsuario()){
        echo"Logado com sucesso";
    }else{
        echo"Não foi possivel logar";
    }
endif;
```

Resumindo: Os dados estão cadastrados mas, ele não retorna a pesquisa verdadeira mesmo logando com os dados certos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não seria porque você não está comparando os valores enviados com colunas da tabela, mas com strings estáticas `'email'` e `'senha'`? Experimente logar exatamente com estas credenciais "email" e "senha", para ver o que acontece. E se necessário corrija assim a query, eliminando as aspas entre o nome das colunas:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE email = :email AND senha = :senha";
```

Ainda existe mais um possível obstáculo, quando a coluna senha é gravada com um hash na tabela. Nesse caso a senha terá que passar pelo mesmo hash antes da comparação.